# Dynamic approach to the TSP

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm having trouble recognizing why this algorithm doesn't return the shortest path for the TSP.

```
vector<int> tsp(int n, vector< vector<float> >& cost)
{
  long nsub = 1 << n;
  vector< vector<float> > opt(nsub, vector<float>(n));

  for (long s = 1; s < nsub; s += 2)
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
      vector<int> subset;
      for (int u = 0; u < n; ++u)
        if (s & (1 << u))
          subset.push_back(u);

      if (subset.size() == 2)
        opt[s][i] = cost[0][i];

      else if (subset.size() > 2) {
        float min_subpath = FLT_MAX;
        long t = s & ~(1 << i);
        for (vector<int>::iterator j = subset.begin(); j != subset.end(); ++j)
          if (*j != i && opt[t][*j] + cost[*j][i] < min_subpath)
            min_subpath = opt[t][*j] + cost[*j][i];
        opt[s][i] = min_subpath;
      }
    }

  vector<int> tour;
  tour.push_back(0);

  bool selected[n];
  fill(selected, selected + n, false);
  selected[0] = true;

  long s = nsub - 1;

  for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
    int j = tour.back();
    float min_subpath = FLT_MAX;
    int best_k;
    for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k)
      if (!selected[k] && opt[s][k] + cost[k][j] < min_subpath) {
        min_subpath = opt[s][k] + cost[k][j];
        best_k = k;
      }
    tour.push_back(best_k);
    selected[best_k] = true;
    s -= 1 << best_k;
  }
  tour.push_back(0);

  return tour;
}
```

For example, on a distance `cost` matrix of just 5 points (5 different nodes in the graph), the algorithm returns a path that's less than optimal.  Any help in recognizing a blatant or small error would be appreciated.  Or any helpful tips as to what's going wrong.

Comment: If you want someone to help pinpoint the exact issue, could you provide a test case that is clearly failing with this code?

Comment: Can you please explain what `opt[i][j]` and `cost[i][j]` contains?

Answer (score 2):

One thing that looks odd is that the main for loop does things even if i is not part of the subset s.

In other words, opt[17][8] will be set to cost[0][8].  opt[17][8] represents the state of being at node 8, and having visited nodes 0 and 4 (because 5=2^0+2^4).

This should be marked as being impossible because if we are at node 8, we must certainly have visited node 8!

I would suggest preventing these cases from occuring by changing:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
  vector<int> subset;
```

to

```
 for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
  vector<int> subset;
  if ((s&(1<<i))==0) {
     opt[s][i]=FLT_MAX;
     continue;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight, this is helpful.  The algorithm is still incorrect, however (with this addition- in fact, the path is exactly the same as before).  I'm still looking for my error, but it doesn't seem to be so obviously there!

Comment: Any other comments you can make?

Answer (score 2):

Nested loop `for(j=` iterates over all nodes in `subset`, including the *starting node*. This results in using uninitialized values `opt[t][0]` and therefore in incorrect optimal path length calculation.

The easiest fix would be to exclude *starting node* from `subset`:

```
for (int u = 1; u < n; ++u)
...
if (subset.size() == 1)
...
else if (subset.size() > 1)
```